# How to organize Android NDK / iOS project

Tags: ios, git, android-ndk

I wrote a game for Android using Android NDK. Core of game logic written in pure C++. So, I want to port it to iOS. I know how to port Java (JNI) wrapping to Objective-C.
My question is how to organize this project on FS? I want to keep a single code base, and I use git ([link](https://github.com/zagayevskiy/Pacman)).

Answer (score 1):

First, note that there should be no need at all do wrap your C++ code: the objective-C extension of the C language is also compatible with C++. So, you can compile your code as "Objective-C++" and directly use C++ classes with Objective-C code.

Second, you can put your code anywhere you wish on the disk. Both eclipse for Android and xcode for iOS will let you include source code into your project from any relative directory.

If you ever need platform-specific native code you can use `#ifdef __ANDROID__` for android-specific code inside your C++.